# How to retrieve the other users LinkedIn profile information?

Tags: java, linkedin-api

I am a new guy to the programming language.Can any please help me by providing the information with respect to retrieve the other users LinkedIn profile information through JAVA Rest web service.

I am sure that when i have log into my LinkedIn profile,can see the others profile and convert their information as document(save as PDF).

Please provide me the information  in the same way how we will convert the others profile into the document through web services.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Ricky,
I have tried by connecting to the LinkedIn api through OAuth with ClientID and Secret Key.But i cant figure out how to get the information of public profile information.

I have followed the things in the following link:
https://github.com/FrankHassanabad/ResumeBuilder/blob/master/resumebuilder/src/main/java/frankhassanabad/com/github/LinkedInDataDownloader.java 

Thanks for your concern

Comment: Can you update the question with some code and the link where you researched?

Comment: Hi Neel

I have researched through through https://github.com/FrankHassanabad/ResumeBuilder/blob/master/resumebuilder/src/main/java/frankhassanabad/com/github/LinkedInDataDownloader.java

Where i have used OAuth to communicate with the LinkedIn api.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this:

[LinkedIN Developer Network API Documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api)

It should point you in the right direction. If you haven't tried to write anything yourself yet, I doubt you will get much help here -- nobody will write your code for you (for free -- maybe someone is willing to do it for an hourly rate, however)

Comment: HI Tim,

Sure i ll check..Thanks